# Variable in name column sql

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I've searched for similar problems and I've found a solution, like:

```
"' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $variable) . '"
```

But nothing, doesn't work for me.

My code:

```
$compra_abi = $_POST['compra_abi'];
$abilita_aumenta = $row_pg[$compra_abi];
$nuovo_livello_abi = $abilita_aumenta+1;
$update_togliexp = "UPDATE utenti SET '".$compra_abi."' = '".$nuovo_livello_abi."' WHERE nome = '".$nome."'";
$result_togliexp = mysql_query($update_togliexp);
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What error(s) are you encountering? A [mcve] is essential for people to be able to help you.

Comment: you dont quote column names in the query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in using a dinamic field as the column name, as far as i can see to solve your problem you should remove the **'** from the column name, like this:

```
$update_togliexp = "UPDATE utenti SET ".$compra_abi." = '".$nuovo_livello_abi."' WHERE nome = '".$nome."'";
```

So you use the comma on the value, so it will be inserted as a string, but not on the column, because MYSQL knows the name

Comment: This fix my problem! Thank you!